# Migrating from Bootstrap 4.0.0 alpha.5 to (alpha.6 and) beta.2 causing rows to wrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

I migrated to Bootstrap (alpha.6, and then) beta.2 from alpha.5, and I'm seeing rows appearing to wrap, and I don't know why. This happens everywhere in my site.

So what used to look like:

[image]

Now looks like:

[image]

The code for this is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="group-label col-md-3 required">10. Birthdate</div>
    <div class="group-label col-md-3 required">11. SSN</div>
    <div class="group-label col-md-6">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

I'm out of ideas for what could be causing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the reason this is happening is because the col divs were not wrapped in an element of class `row`. This would look like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="group-label col-md-3 required">10. Birthdate</div>
    <div class="group-label col-md-3 required">11. SSN</div>
    <div class="group-label col-md-6">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```